# "Had hosted" vs "had been hosting": What's the difference?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect, progressive-aspect

Steve Irwin was the host of various nature shows on TV before he was killed in an accident.

> Steve had hosted nature shows for a long time before he had his accident.

What's the difference between that sentence and

> Steve had been hosting nature shows for a long time before he had his accident.

Which is more correct?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct; the second gives a strong indication that the hosting was still ongoing at the moment in time when he had his accident (though he was actually filming, if  I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

They are nearly equivalent.

The second form brings focus to the duration or interval of hosting rather than just the sequence of events.  In this case, the "before" suggests that the interval has completed, and should probably be replaced with "when" to allow the accident to be still within the period of hosting.